# Get index of item in array found with filter Angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs-filter

I have an array of pages in a book. I would like to find the index of a page that I have used filter to find. I'm farming it out to a function which works, but I wonder I can't combine indexOf or findIndex or something similar with the filter?

To get a specific page, I use this code:

```
  getPage(pageNumber: number) {
    return this.pages.filter(page => page.pageNumber == pageNumber)[0];
  }
```

Then, to delete a page I use the following:

```
  deletePage() {
    let deletedPageLocation = this.findPageIndex();
    this.pages.splice(deletedPageLocation, 1);
    this.pagesChanged.next(this.pages.slice());
  }

  findPageIndex() {
    for(var i=0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
      if (this.pages[i].pageNumber == this.currentPage) {
        return i;
      }
    }
```

I would like to simplify into something like:

```
let deletedPageLocation = this.pages.indexOf(this.pages.filter(page => page.pageNumber == pageNumber)[0]);
```

But I couldn't figure out a way to get it to return the value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
var found = $filter('filter')($scope.pages, { pageNumberinPages: pagenumberSearching },true);
```

It will return you array of objects matches your search.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using `find` and `indexOf`. I find it much easier than using filter. Here's a code sample in terms of your question:

```
deletePage(item){
    let deleteItem = this.pages.find(this.findIndexToUpdate, item.pageId);   
    let index = this.pages.indexOf(deleteItem);

    if(index > -1){
      this.pages.splice(index, 1);
    }


  }

  findIndexToUpdate(item) {
       console.log("this: " + this)
        return item.pageId === this;
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJOv5m1Z19jUZcR1kga8?p=preview)